# How do I connect a non-AMP page to an AMP page?

Tags: amp-html

I want to implement Google AMP on my blog. I've already created the AMP version of the blog articles. For example:

```
# Regular version
http://myblog.com/a-cool-blog-post

# AMP version
http://myblog.com/amp/a-cool-blog-post
```

How to do I connect them together so that Google can index and serve the AMP version when users search for my posts on mobile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your non-AMP blog post, add the `amphtml` link tag and set the `href` to the AMP version:

```html
<link rel="amphtml" href="http://myblog.com/amp/a-cool-blog-post">
```

Next, in your AMP blog post, add the `canonical` link tag and set the `href` to the non-AMP version:

```html
<link rel="canonical" href="http://myblog.com/a-cool-blog-post">
```

See Politico's *Warren moves to outflank Trump on trade* ([regular version](https://www.politico.com/story/2019/07/29/elizabeth-warren-trump-trade-2020-1439186) | [AMP version](https://www.politico.com/amp/story/2019/07/29/elizabeth-warren-trump-trade-2020-1439186)) for a live example.

*Source:* [Make your pages discoverable](https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/optimize-and-measure/discovery/)